# How To show only one id in laravel

Tags: laravel-9

I found a problem when I wanna show my data's detail, it always take two data.
this is my controller

```
public function show(Transaction $transactions)
    {
        $tran=Transaction::find($transactions);
        return $tran;
        return view('admin.transaction.show', compact('tran','transactions'));
    }
```

This is my show Button

```
<td>
<a href="{{route('transactions.show', $transaction->id) }}"><i class="far fa-eye" style="color:blue"></i></a>
</td>
```

and this is the return

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: why you are returning $tran ? double check your code

Comment: unfortunately, your description of the problem is not that helpful for us. To make it simpler, kindly answer the following question:  **what do you expect to have as a result ?**

Comment: I expect the result will only take 1 data. not 2 data like what i showed above

Comment: please clarify what do you mean by `data` ? It's so confusing, do you mean the `$tran` variable maybe ?!

Comment: you can see when I return $tran, It take 2 id from my table. and i expect that will show only 1 id which choosen

Comment: There is no exception error, it's just that the id taken by the $tran variable is not as desired as shown in the picture. it should take only 1 id, but this takes 2 ids at once.